# How to stop state transition when state satisfies some condition?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm quite new to scalaz/cats and have a question about `State` monad (`cats` or `scalaz` does not matter). Consider the following well-known example with `Stack`:

```
object StateTest {

  type Stack = List[Int]

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(transition.run(List(1, 2, 3, 4)).value) //(List(4),Some(3))
    println(transition.run(List(1, 2)).value) //(List(),None)

  }

  def transition: State[Stack, Option[Int]] = for {
    _ <- pop
    _ <- pop
    a <- pop
  } yield a

  def pop: State[Stack, Option[Int]] = State {
    case x::xs => (xs, Some(x))
    case Nil => (Nil, None)
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want to perform state transition (`pop`) till the state (`List[Int]`) satisfies some condition (I want to check `List[Int]::isEmpty`) and after that immediately stop.

In the current implementation I can only know if the state satisfies the condition after I invoke `run`.

Is it possible to do so in cats/scalaz with State monad or I need something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the state monad parameterized by another monad representing the termination.

In general, such parameterized monads are called *monad transformers*. In this specific case, you would use the `StateT` monad transformer. Modulo some implementation details, `StateT` is equivalent to

```
type StateT[F[_], S, A] = S => F[(S, A)]
```

Now you can choose `F` to be `Option`, representing immediate termination.

```
import scalaz.StateT
import scalaz.std.option._

object StateTest {

  type Stack = List[Int]

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(transition.run(List(1, 2, 3, 4))) // Some((List(4), 3))
    println(transition.run(List(1, 2)))       // None
  }

  def transition: StateT[Option, Stack, Int] = for {
    _ <- pop
    _ <- pop
    a <- pop
  } yield a

  def pop: StateT[Option, Stack, Int] = StateT {
    case x::xs => Some((xs, x))
    case Nil   => None
  }
}
```

If you want to return some value of type `B` even in the case of early termination, you can use `Either[B, ?]` instead of `Option` to parameterize `StateT`:

```
type ErrorOr[A] = Either[String, A]

def pop1: StateT[ErrorOr, Stack, Int] = StateT {
  case x::xs => Right((xs, x))
  case Nil   => Left("Cannot pop from an empty stack.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how about stopping exactly when we reach `None`. I mean we don't know the initial size (e.g. 100). And I want to pop all elements by performing the state transition. 100-lines long for comprehension looks kind of scary...

Comment: I suspect I need to wrap `StateT[Option, Stack, Int]` into another monad... No?

Comment: Actually, I can execute the state transition in fixed size batches... and than check if it reaches the state I need... In my case it would have batch size = 3 (3 `pop`s) and then run after each transition. Does it look too weird?

Comment: Use recursion: `def popAll: StateT[Option, Stack, Int] = pop flatMap (i => popAll)`. If the initial `pop` returns `None`, the argument to `flatMap` will never execute. If it returns some int `i`, this `i` is passed to the argument to `flatMap` and we continue with what it returns, in this case call `popAll` recursively.